# array data placement in php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

how can i arrange an array data in phpp so that it can match 2 or more values?

EX:
users.php

```
$USERS["username1"] = "password1";
```

direct.php

```
include("users.php");

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if ($USERS[$user]==$pass) { 

echo "welcome";
}
```

so in the $USERS array the value will satify the if statement if the user inputs

"username1" and "passsword1"

what i want to do is allow the "username1" to be paired with other values

```
 $USERS["username1"] = "password1" , "password3" , "password109";
```

even if the user inputs any of these 3

```
"password1" , "password3" , "password109"
```

it will satisfy the if statement is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You can store another array as the value of an array. However you will need to adjust your if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you need is [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array)

```
$users['username1'] = array('password1','password3','azeadnfksfn');

if (in_array($password,$users[$user])) {
    echo 'Welcome';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for that. `$USERS["username1"]` with passwords should be an array, and then you can do something like this:

```
include("users.php");

$USERS["username1"] = array("password1" , "password3" , "password109");

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if (in_array($pass,$USERS["username1"])) { 

   echo "welcome";
}
```